# Work with instance of class in C#

Tags: c#, class, colors, system.windows.media

I have some troubles with a class instance and don’t understand the issue. I’m working with colored text in different classes and therefore my idea was to define this colors only one time so changing of them will be much easier.

For the definition of the colors, I specified a class called MyColors. I used System.Windows.Media and defined the RGB colors using the Color class. My idea was to specify each color as privat and add a property that generated the read access to this color, but Visual Studio sends me an error.

```
namespace MyProject
{
class MyColor
{
    private Color myGreen = new Color();
    myGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets my green
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>my green</value>
    static public Color MyGreen
    {
        get
        {
            return myGreen;
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

The sixth line "myGreen..." generates the mistake. If I change the code to the following one, it works.

```
namespace MyProject
{
class MyColor
{
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets my green
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>my green</value>
    static public Color MyGreen
    {
        get
        {
            Color myGreen = new Color();
            myGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
            return myGreen;
        }

    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Can anybody explain me what I’m doing wrong. Looks like I have a wrong understanding of a class.

Comment: You can't just put arbitrary code at the class level, it needs to be inside a method.

Comment: Add the details of the error to the question

Comment: Also, `return MyGreen;` should be `return myGreen;`. Another also, `System.Drawing.Color.Green`.

Comment: Visual Studio sends the error: The Name "myGreen" isn't available in the current context. (translated from German)

Comment: Sorry, the return myGreen inside of get starts actually with a small letter, MyGreen is a mistake in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the approach you used in your first code snipped, since it doesn't require to instantiate a new `Color` every time that `MyGreen` property is accessed. But it contains a few errors:

1. If you want the `MyGreen` property to be `static`, the underlying instance returned by its getter (`get { ... }`) must be declared as `static` too.
2. You cannot create an instance in the class scope using multiple lines of code. That kind of code can only be executed within an inner scope like a constructor, a property or a method. Since it's unnecessary to instantiate it twice (first using the `Color()` constructor and then using `Color.FromRgb` which basically returns a new `Color` instance with the specified `RGB` values), everything can be converted into a one-liner without changing the wanted behavior.

Below how your class should look like:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyColor
    {
        private static Color s_MyGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);

        public static Color MyGreen
        {
            get { return s_MyGreen; }

        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Please don't ask for accepts/votes here, it's considered very bad behaviour.

Comment: I think it should be ok when you do it in order to educate a new user. Often, new users close the SO tab once the problem is solved, leaving their questions "unanswered" and forgetting to reward any effort made to help them. On the top of that, I didn't force him to accept **my** answer, I just told him to consider accepting it if it was what he was looking for.